# How to convert a date to dd.MM.yyyy format in Java?

Tags: java, date, jdk6

How can I convert the date`(Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 IST 2015)` in the format `MM.dd.yyyy` or `dd.MM.yyyy`?

I tried using the below approach

```
    String dateStr = "Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 IST 2015";

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(dateStr));
```

but got,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Cannot format given Object as a Date
```

Comment: First you have to parse the string as a date and then you can format it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to parse the string to Date then format that Date

```
String dateStr = "Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 IST 2015";

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
DateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter1.format(formatter.parse(dateStr)));
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/G0PU8i)

Comment: If the date is Mon Jan 32 00:00:00 IST 2015, it gets converted to date of next month(in this case, 01.02.2015), how can I prevent this.

Comment: use `setLenient(false)` to validate date check the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

```
String dateStr = "Mon Jan 12 00:00:00 IST 2015";
```

First you have to parse your string to a date:

```
DateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");
Date date = parser.parse(dateStr);
```

and then you can format it:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```